Prove that the field $K((t))$ is not algebraically closed
Consider the field
$$F_{1}=\{f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_i t^i: a_i \in K, \alpha \in \mathbb Z \}$$
With $K$ a field.
I want to see that this field is not algebraically closed, i.e. that there is a polynomial $\sum_{i} a_i t^i$ which is not factorizable or has no roots within the same field, I thought of considering the following field
$$F_{2}=\{f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_i t^{\frac{i}{k}}: a_i \in K, \alpha \in \mathbb Z, k \in \Bbb N \}$$
I see clearly that $F_{1} \subset F_{2}$ and that some element of $F_2$ that is not in $F_1$ can serve as an example of an irreducible polynomial in $F_1$, e.g.
$$p(t)=y^n-t$$
If $y=t ^ {\frac{1}{n}} \notin F_1$ then $y^n-t=0$. I think this could be a possible argument to justify what I want, any suggestions? I appreciate any help!

"i.e. that there is a polynomial $\sum_{i} a_i t^i$...": what you wrote is an element of $F_1$, not a polynomial with coefficients in $F_1$.

$F_2$ is useless, and $y$ should denote a polynomial indeterminate. That said, your idea is fine: the polynomial $y^2-t\in F_1[y]$ has indeed no root in $F_1$.

@AnneBauval Thank you for the accuracy

To justify that $F_1$ is indeed a field, here is an interesting link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Multiplicative_inverse

Your field $F_2=K\{\{t\}\}$ of Puiseux series
is useless, and $y$
should denote a polynomial indeterminate. That said, your idea is fine: the polynomial
$$p(\color{red}y)=y^2-t\in F_1[y]$$
has indeed no root in the field $F_1=K((t))$ of formal Laurent series, i.e. $t$ has no square root in that field. Indeed, any non-zero square in $F_1$ has an even valuation.

Here’s one way of attacking this problem.
Assume $k((t))$ is algebraically closed.
Since $k((t))$ is the field of fractions of $k[[t]]$, and the latter is a UFD, any root of $X^2-t=0$ must land in $k[[t]]$ (mimic the proof of the corresponding statement for monic integral polynomials)
But it is a simple computation that the square of no power series in $k[[t]]$ gives you $t$ (check the order on both sides)

How can you be sure that it really is a field of fractions?

$k((t))$ is a subset of the field of fractions and it is also a field in it itself. On the other hand, the field of fractions is in some sense, the “smallest” field containing a domain.
